# How does another user access my PostgreSQL database in pgAdmin?

Tags: database, postgresql, pgadmin

SQL newbie here.
I have pgAdmin installed on a shared location from where I am setting up a PostgreSQL database.

I want to give my colleagues access to this database.
All colleagues that should have access to the database, also have access to the shared location.

I found many helpful threads that helped me set up additional users with all the rights and privileges etc.

But how do my colleagues actually login as one of these users and access the database? Do they have to set up their own postgreSQL and pgAdmin client for example?

I tried to login myself as one of the users that I set up but I haven't found a way to do that as well.
I automatically login as the 'postgres' user and can't find a way to login as another user.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Better asked on the sister site, https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Clarify what “shared location” means exactly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We all use the Microsoft environment and we can access the same files and folders through sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

Your users enter their username and password into the  [*Login* dialog](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/login.html).

As the [DBA](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_administrator), you must establish that username and password ahead of time, and assign privileges. Alternatively, pgAdmin now supports using [LDAP](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol) for logins.

[image: screenshot of pgAdmin 4 Login dialog]

> Do they have to set up their own postgreSQL

No, not necessary. Many users can share one Postgres server, a “cluster” in SQL-standard terminology. Each Postgres server/cluster can hold one or more databases. You can establish separate databases (“catalogs”) for users and/or let them share access to a database/catalog.

> Do they have to set up their own … pgAdmin client

Yes. Any user must have the *pgAdmin* app installed on their own computer.

Or you provide some other app that connects to your Postgres cluster and catalog. That app could be any of several other admin tools similar to pgAdmin. Or that app could be some purpose-built app you obtain or write yourself such as a [Java](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(software_platform)) app with [JavaFX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX) that uses [JDBC driver](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) to connect to Postgres, or a [Xojo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xojo) app that uses its bundled driver to connect to Postgres, etc.

Comment: Thank you! I have one follow-up question. I don't get the blue login dialog, when I start pgAdmin I automatically login as 'postgres' and I am prompted for the master password. I have created multiple users/roles but how can I get the login dialog?

Comment: @Yosh021 Stop using your automatic login?

Comment: I feel so silly for asking this but how do I do that? When starting pgAdmin I just enter the database and all it is asking for is the master password. I never get the blue login dialog that you showed in your answer.